# Using a condition with an on duplicate key update

Tags: mysql

I am writing a SQL statement that updates current records. The problem I am having is that if one of the columns has a specific value then I don't want the value to be overwritten. If the value of the status column in the table equals Received I don't want it to be overwritten.
Here is my sample code:

```
INSERT INTO transfer_order (invoice_id, contact_id, ship_date, ship_info, tracking_number, date_created, date_modified, account_number, shipping, discount, status) 
VALUES ('$invoice_id', $contact_id, $ship_date, $shipper_id, $tracking_number , $date_created, $date_modified, $account_name, $shipping_cost, $discount, $status) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE contact_id=VALUES(contact_id),
ship_date=VALUES(ship_date), tracking_number=VALUES(tracking_number), 
ship_info=VALUES(ship_info), date_created=VALUES(date_created), 
date_modified=VALUES(date_modified),shipping=VALUES(shipping),status=VALUES(status)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
INSERT INTO transfer_order 
(invoice_id, contact_id, ship_date, ship_info, tracking_number, date_created, date_modified, account_number, shipping, discount, status) 
VALUES ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
contact_id = CASE status 
                WHEN 'Received' THEN VALUES(contact_id)
             END , 
ship_date = CASE status
                WHEN 'Received' THEN VALUES(ship_date)
            END, 
tracking_number = VALUES(tracking_number), 
ship_info = VALUES(ship_info), 
date_created = VALUES(date_created), 
date_modified = VALUES(date_modified), 
shipping = VALUES(shipping),
status = VALUES(status)
```

Comment: I attempted making the changes with the code you provided and it still overwrote the previous record.